# Ask NPM to download the TypeScript source, not just the *.d.ts files

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to ask NPM to download the TypeScript source files for dependencies, instead of just the `*.d.ts` and compiled `*.js` files?

I'm using VS Code's `Go To Definition` feature, but for dependencies it just takes me to `.d.ts` files that lack implementation logic - this makes it harder to understand what my dependencies are doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading TypeScript source files via NPM is only possible if those files have been published to NPM. The general convention for TypeScript projects is to only publish the `dist/` directory which is generated post-compilation, with `.d.ts` files included to aid development that uses the library. If this is the case, then the only (inconvenient) way to view the source TypeScript files is to find out if/where the source code is hosted.